# Substitute multiple values by a list of other values in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, replace

How do I substitute multiple values in Postgres?  I need to do something like the following:

```
In column C
Case current value = x then replace by a
else if current value is y then replace by b
else if current value is z then replace by c...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CASE WHEN`:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column_name =
      CASE WHEN column_name = 'x' THEN 'a'
           WHEN column_name = 'y' THEN 'b'
           WHEN column_name = 'z' THEN 'c'
           ...
           ELSE column_name                 -- default
     END
-- WHERE id = ?
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/394672)**</kbd>

Comment: This is a perfect solution with excellent performance.  Thanks lad2025.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to be working with text (or something that can be cast to text) you can try the translate function.

> translate(string text, from text, to text) text:
>
> Any character in string that matches a character in the from set is
>   replaced by the corresponding character in the to set. If from is
>   longer than to, occurrences of the extra characters in from are
>   removed.  translate('12345', '143', 'ax') a2x5`